# Memoir \subbottom define spacing between two figures

Tags: memoir

How do I define the spacing between two figures, when using \subbottom ?
My code looks like the following:

```
\begin{figure}
\centerfloat
\subbottom[Manual segmentation of colon and liver. The two green segmentations are colon and the red is liver.]{%
\includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth]{img/selection_colon_liver_thin.pdf}}
\subbottom[Histogram of the two segmentations of colon and liver made with 200 bins.]{%
\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{img/histogram_colon_liver.pdf}}
\caption{Needs caption}
\end{figure}
```

The captions are two long, so they get "merged" together. How do I separate them?
[image: Screendump of the two captions]

Comment: (1) make fully compilable MWEs, not sniplets. (2) add say `\quad` between the subbottoms, they do not provide any horizontal padding.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to make it into an answer

`\subbottom` does not provide padding, but manually adding, say, `\quad` between the `\subbottom`'s should do the trick